# how to get a callback_data from an inline keyboard

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

Need help with inline keyboard. I made a button, but what to do with the callback? I understand I need to somehow get a callback_data and issue a new message.

Comment: and in whitch code you have this problem? please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

when a person clicks on your inline button you will get an [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) of type [callback_query](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) (this field will be present) which will contain the callback_data. you need to handle this update and respond properly.

check the documentation for more information.
hint:

> NOTE: After the user presses a callback button, Telegram clients will display a progress bar until you call answerCallbackQuery. It is, therefore, necessary to react by calling answerCallbackQuery even if no notification to the user is needed (e.g., without specifying any of the optional parameters).